# Error in if (STATUS != 0) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I want to acquire the optimized allocation of a set of the asset, so I use the package `fPortfolio` and `BLCOP`. Here is my code,

```
library(xts);library(fPortfolio);library(BLCOP)
sh_return <- xts(ret[,-1],order.by = as.Date(ret[,1]))
prior_mean <- colMeans(sh_return)
prior_mean
prior_cov_matrix <- cov(sh_return)

## onstruct the confidenec interval
pick_matrix <- matrix(0,2,ncol(sh_return))
colnames(pick_matrix) <- colnames(sh_return)
pick_matrix[1,1:4] <- 1
pick_matrix[2,c(1,2,5,ncol(sh_return)-1)] <- c(0.5,0.6,-1,0.8)
pick_matrix
# views
q <- c(0.4,0.32)
confidence <- c(90,95)
views <- BLViews(pick_matrix,q,confidence,assetNames = colnames(sh_return))
views
# posterior
tau <- 0.3
posterior <- posteriorEst(views,tau=tau,prior_mean,prior_cov_matrix)

# optimazation
optimal_portfolio <- optimalPortfolios.fPort(posterior,inputData = NULL,spec = NULL,constraints = "LongOnly",optimizer = "tangencyPortfolio",numSimulations  = 100)
```

And the error turns out:

```
Error in if (STATUS != 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

The problem is, when I check the source code, it seems fine to me and there is no such `STATUS` that exists. Therefore, I have no idea how this code could go wrong like this. Any idea could be helpful.

Or if you want to test the data, here is the code from the source file of the package, the same error exists:

```
entries <- c(0.001005,0.001328,-0.000579,-0.000675,0.000121,0.000128,
             -0.000445, -0.000437, 0.001328,0.007277,-0.001307,-0.000610,
             -0.002237,-0.000989,0.001442,-0.001535, -0.000579,-0.001307,
             0.059852,0.027588,0.063497,0.023036,0.032967,0.048039,-0.000675,
             -0.000610,0.027588,0.029609,0.026572,0.021465,0.020697,0.029854,
             0.000121,-0.002237,0.063497,0.026572,0.102488,0.042744,0.039943,
             0.065994 ,0.000128,-0.000989,0.023036,0.021465,0.042744,0.032056,
             0.019881,0.032235 ,-0.000445,0.001442,0.032967,0.020697,0.039943,
             0.019881,0.028355,0.035064 ,-0.000437,-0.001535,0.048039,0.029854,
             0.065994,0.032235,0.035064,0.079958 )

varcov <- matrix(entries, ncol = 8, nrow = 8)
mu <- c(0.08, 0.67,6.41, 4.08, 7.43, 3.70, 4.80, 6.60) / 100
pick <- matrix(0, ncol = 8, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:8]))
pick[1,7] <- 1
pick[2,1] <- -1; pick[2,2] <- 1
pick[3, 3:6] <- c(0.9, -0.9, .1, -.1)
confidences <- 1 / c(0.00709, 0.000141, 0.000866)
views <- BLViews(pick, c(0.0525, 0.0025, 0.02), confidences, letters[1:8])
posterior <- posteriorEst(views, tau = 0.025, mu, varcov )

optimalPortfolios.fPort(posterior, optimizer = "tangencyPortfolio")
```

Comment: BLViews is undefined

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, could you explain more about this? BLViews is a function in package `BLCOP`

Comment: Ok I see now you mentionned on top, better to include library calls in your reproducible code

Comment: OK，thx for the advice~

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I guess is something wrong with the compatibility between R and the package since even the source file code goes wrong.